# C parsing string to array of chars without any lib functions

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

What I am trying to do, is parse string, containing spaces to array of arrays of chars. So if input was "ab cd ef", I want my array to be array[0]==ab, array[1]==cd,array[2]==ef. I hope that that makes it clear. Problem however is that i cant use any lib functions. No string.h, no fget, just scanf and printf. Here is snipplet of my code:

```
char word[25] = "";
char *words[25];

for (int i = 0; i <= find_length(input); i++){
    if(input[i] == ' ' || i == find_length(input)){
        words[position] = word;
        printf("%s%d ",words[position], position);
        position++;
        counter = 0;
        word[0] = '\0';
    }
    else{
        word[counter] = input[i];
        counter++;
    }
}

position = 0;

while(counter < 5){
    printf("%s%d ",words[position], position);
    counter++;
}
```

First I parse string into individual words and then I try to put them into array. I hope that my logic is correct. So the problem is, that first printf (one in for loop) prints proper values and their positions. However second printf (which is only to make sure that string was parsed properly) prints just 0.
So for example input "ab cd ef" gives:

> ab0 cd1 ef2 0 0 0 0 0

I suspect that problem is that I am not adding values to the array of arrays, just assigning pointers. And since I dump "word", they point to nothing. If that is correct, how do I assign values instead of pointers?

Of course this assumption might be wrong, if so could you point me to my mistake and how to fix it? Thank you.

PS: I know that I should strcpy value of string not = it, but as I said, I cant use any lib functions other than scanf and printf (find_length is my own function)

Comment: What is `input`?  Its type, its value?

Comment: Where is your code for `find_length()`?

Comment: Check your use of  `counter` and `offset`. They are mixed up in the last five lines of code.

Comment: Assuming your `find_length()` does the equivalent of `strlen()`, I think visualizing your code will help: http://pastebin.com/mbLJ0ueY . Copy and paste the url in this pastebin to your browser. Wait some seconds for it to load and then navigate with the forward and back buttons. This is not spam... I didn't paste the link here because it's too big to fit a comment and shortened URLs are frowned upon.

Comment: `words[position] = word;`: You set same address of buffer . then buffer reset as `word[0] = '\0';`

Comment: Input is char* and gets value from scanf, find_length gets length of string, yeah I messed those two up, and thank you for visualization. It would seem that my assumption was correct and I am indeed pointing to nothing. How would I fix that however?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really agree with @harper 's answer because the main problem is the following, as the OP almost figured out himself:

> I suspect that problem is that I am not adding values to the array of
>   arrays, just assigning pointers. And since I dump "word", they point
>   to nothing. If that is correct, how do I assign values instead of
>   pointers?

This code will make `words[0]` point to the block of memory associated with the char array `word`. Then `words[1]` will point to that same block. Then `words[3]` and so on..

In the end, all elements inside the char* array `words[]` will point to the char array `word[]`, which will contain a `'\0'` as its first element, seeing that the OP does this `word[0] = '\0';` repeatedly.

So my proposed fix, besides what's already mentioned about the while loop at end, would be to allocate memory for each substring and then copy the contents of `word[]` with a simple `for` loop.

So this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= find_length(input); i++){
    if(input[i] == ' ' || i == find_length(input)){
        words[position] = word;
        printf("%s%d ",words[position], position);
        position++;
        counter = 0;
        word[0] = '\0';
    }
```

Would become this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= find_length(input); i++) {
    if(input[i] == ' ' || i == find_length(input)) {
    words[position] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (counter + 1));
        for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
            words[position][j] = word[j];
        words[position][counter] = '\0';
        printf("%s%d ", words[position], position);
        position++;
        counter = 0;
        word[0] = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: i tried this and it gives segmentation fault. Am I initializing arrays correctly?

Comment: I assumed your `find_length()` behaved exactly as `strlen()`. Maybe I was wrong about your implementation. If you replace your function with `strlen()` does the seg fault still happen? (just for testing.. I know you can't use `strlen()` )

Comment: I still got seg fault even after replacing it with strlen()

Comment: Oh, forget what I said. I think your seg fault comes from the fact that your while loop at the end goes from 0 to 5 (not included) when it should go from 0 to 3 (not included)

Comment: No, the problem was bad allocation of memory. I changed initialization of my words array to **words and allocated memory via malloc. Now it works fine. Your answer however was correct in copying values of one array to another instead of pointers so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last lines with this snippet:

```
position = 0;

while(position < 5) {
    printf("%s%d ", words[position], position);
    position++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved 0 problem. But that didnt solve problem with arrays.